# How to change port's Local Address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

I want to open `port: 8332` on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 dedicated server.

I already opened it with `sudo ufw allow 8332` command and also on server comand panel, but when I want to check if it is open it's still closed.

Checked with `sudo netstat -ltup` and saw that port is using local address localhost instead of `0.0.0.0`

So it is accesible only from localhost and not any address right?
Is there a way to change port's Local Address to `0.0.0.0`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be, but this needs to be configured in the application that is listening on port 8332.